# Logging Jedis client with Spring

Tags: spring, redis, jedis

I tried logging other instances using logging.level.my.package and they work just fine, I wonder why I cant get logging.level.redis.clients.jedis to work? Simply just want to trace jedis processes in a running process.

edited:

I kept getting

```
Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

though not all the time, but this results in loss of data that was supposed to go in redis. that's why i need to find out whats causing this exception.

on the config i specifically set its timeout to 30 seconds but it took less than 10 seconds for it to throw timeout exception.

Comment: Please, show examples of your code and/or errors you are getting

Comment: @VictorMarchuk i want to find out whats causing a timeout error through logging, but it seems logging.level.redis.clients.jedis just wont work the way it does with the other.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of leaving logging messages, Jedis throws JedisException (and the descendant classes) which wraps the origin reason (Exception). Only JedisSentinelPool does logging but it's a really small place.

So you can't get further logging messages though you change the log level of Jedis package.

And Jedis uses Java Socket internally, and timeout exception is being thrown by Socket, so unless timeout value is not set correctly, Jedis can't know why timeout is happened. It's just a general Socket exception.